# Weird OpenGL issue when factoring out code

Tags: c++, opengl, struct, buffer

So I have some code that creates a buffer and puts some vertices in it:

```
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

I also bind it to a shader attribute:

```
glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "pos");
```

And, finally, draw it:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Of course, there is other code, but all of this stuff runs fine (displays a red triangle on the screen)

However, the instant I try to factor this stuff out in a struct, nothing will display (here is one of the methods):

```
void loadVerts(GLfloat verts[], int indices)
    {
        GLuint vertexbuffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(indice, indices, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(indice);
        indice++;
        buffers.push_back(vertexbuffer);
    }
```

I've quadruple checked this code, and I've also traced it to make sure it would match the code above whenever its called. My draw call is almost the same as my original:

```
void draw()
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.at(0));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }
```

I've also tried making this a class, and adding/changing many parts of the code. `buffers` and `indice` are just some vars to keep track of buffers and attribute indexes. `buffers` is an `std::vector<GLuint>` FWIW.

Comment: You do know that binding a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is only useful if you do something like call `glVertexAttribPointer(...)` immediately afterwards, right? [There was a similar question asked recently that you may find helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635341/properly-update-vertex-buffer-objects/26635853#26635853).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I did call `glVertexAttribPointer`...

Comment: I am referring to this line of code that does not do anything `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.at(0));` in `void draw (void)`. That line of code does not belong there, or it needs a `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` call after it.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Hmmmmm. In my original code I just called those two lines and it drew fine. Why would I need to call `glVertexAttribPointer` immediately after?

Comment: Because binding the array buffer by itself does not do anything to affect the behavior of `glDrawArrays (...)`. There are only a couple of commands that are affected by what is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` is one of them. So logically, the only reason you would bind a VBO there is if you were going to setup a vertex pointer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman So I added this call, but to no avail: `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);`. I put it immediately after `glBindBuffer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
void loadVerts(GLfloat verts[], int indices)
{
    ...
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The type of the `verts` argument is a pointer to `GLfloat`. Your function signature is equivalent to:

```
void loadVerts(GLfloat* verts, int indices)
```

So `sizeof(verts)`, which is used as the second argument to `glBufferData()`, is 4 on a 32-bit architecture, 8 on a 64-bit architecture.

You will need to pass the size as an additional argument to this function, and use that value as the second argument to `glBufferData()`.

These statements also look somewhat confusing:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(indice, indices, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(indice);
```

I can't tell if there's a real problem, but you have two variables with very similar names that are used very differently. `indice` needs to be the location of the attribute in your vertex shader, while `indices` needs to be the number of components in the attribute.