# VAOs and VBOs for rendering different objects

Tags: c++, c, opengl, vbo, vao

I wrote this "Model" class to load .obj files and allocate data for them in a VBO.
Its code is something like this: (notice how it doesn't use VAOs)

```
class Model {...}

void Model::LoadOBJ(const char *file)
{
    //load vertices, normals, UVs, and put them all in _vec, which is a private data member of std::vector<glm::vec3>
    ...

    //if an .obj file is loaded for the first time, generate a buffer object and bind it
    if(glIsBuffer(_vbo) == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);//_vbo is a private data member
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
    }
    
    //load the data in the array buffer object
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * _vec.size(), &_vec[0][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Model::Draw()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _numVertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I used to think that the next code would work fine for rendering two different objects:

```
void init()
{
    //vao dummy (?)
    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    //load 3d models
    Model cube = load("cube.obj");
    Model cow = load("cow.obj");

    //the next two lines should be valid for both objects?
    glVertexAttribPointer(prog.GetAttribLocation("vertex"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(prog.GetAttribLocation("vertex"));
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    //draw cube:
    //some matrix transformations
    ...
    cube.Draw();

    //draw cow:
    //some matrix transformations
    ...
    cow.Draw()

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

but it turns out that OpenGL will just draw two cows or two cubes. (depends on which model I load last in init())
[image: two cows]
[image: two cubes]

By the way, I'm pretty sure that in the first image, opengl did try to draw two cows, but the glDrawArrays() function was called with the amount of vertices needed for a cube.

So what am I missing? Do I need a different VAO for every buffer object or something like that?

Comment: I wrote some pseudo-code to show why `//the next two lines should be valid for both objects?` is an invalid assumption, but if you want the gist of it see warsac's answer :P Once you get the right idea, you should come to the realization that the first and last lines of code in `void Model::Draw ()` actually do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### "Current" state is to blame here, particularly in relation to `glVertexAttribPointer`.

All calls to `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` establish memory pointers relative to the Buffer Object *currently* bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. We tend to call a Buffer Object that is bound to that location a ***Vertex Buffer Object***, but in reality a single Buffer Object can be used for multiple purposes and they do not actually have a type.

#### Think of it sort of like this in modern OpenGL:

```
GLuint GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING = 0; // Only 1 or 2 commands in GL care about this state
GLuint GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BINDING = 0; // 0 is an invalid VAO (if this is 0, most vertex commands will generate `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`).

// Generic GPU-side Memory Store
struct GLBufferObject {
  GLsizeiptr* gpu_base_addr;
} *gl_buffer_objects;

// Vertex Array State
struct GLVertexArrayObject {
  GLsizeiptr* attribute_pointers [GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTES];
  GLboolean   attribute_enabled  [GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTES];
  GLuint      GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING;
} *gl_array_objects;

void glBindVertexArray (GLuint array)
{
  GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BINDING = array;
}

void glBindBuffer (GLenum target, GLuint buffer)
{
  if (target == GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING = buffer;
}

void glVertexAttribPointer (GLuint index, ..., const GLvoid* offset)
{
  GLBufferObject*      current_vbo = &gl_buffer_objects [GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING];
  GLVertexArrayObject* current_vao = &gl_array_objects  [GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BINDING];

  current_vao->attribute_pointers [index] = current_vbo->gpu_base_addr + offset;
}
```

The point of this pseudo-code is to show you that there is only one command in OpenGL where what you have bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` matters in your entire code: `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`.

All other commands such as `glDrawArrays (...)` actually use the state stored in "`current_vao`" as shown in the mock implementation of `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`.

---

In the end, your non-use of VAOs is actually an issue. You are overwriting the attribute pointer for the ***only*** VAO that your software currently uses with whichever model was loaded last.

Review which states `GLVetexArrayObject` stores in the pseudo-code, and then consider refactoring your own code to take advantage of that. Otherwise, you are going to have to make at least one call to `glVertexAttribPointer` every time you call `void Model::Draw()`.

*For a less interesting explanation, see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314787/use-of-vertex-array-objects-and-vertex-buffer-objects/23315318#23315318).*

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the vertex attrib code (setting and enabling) to your draw function after you bind the buffer. These calls will act on your currently bound buffer.

If you use different vaos for different models the attrib data will be stored in the vao and you will not need to rebind the attribs (just change vao) each time you draw a new object.