# What's the term 'batch' exactly means in 3D computer science (3D engine)?

Tags: opengl, 3d, vao, batching

I'm developping a 3D application using OpenGL.

I have a misconception about a part of the following post: [OpenGL VAO best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923174/opengl-vao-best-practices)

I'm not sure about the meaning of the term 'batch' in this post.

Does it means for each object of the scene ?
So does it suggest to create a VAO for each object of the scene or several objects ?
Does a batch refers to several objects sharing the same materials, transformations and shading ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batch is simply a, well, "batch" (=bunch) of primitives, i.e. points, lines or triangles drawn by making a single `glDraw…` call. There's no deeper maging behind this.

> Does it means for each object of the scene?

No. OpenGL doesn't know what a "model" is. This concept goes totally beyond what OpenGL does. OpenGL merely draws points, lines or triangles to the screen, and that's it.

> So does it suggest to create a VAO for each object of the scene or several objects?

No, it suggests that you create VAOs and VBOs in such a way, that you can coalesce the maximum number of primitives (= triangle | line | point) that can be drawn with a minimum number of `glDraw…` calls into a single VAO/VBO.

For example say you'd render a warehouse full of cardboard boxes, where each box has a (slightly) different shape (think of the self service section in an IKEA store; I'm pretty sure those look about the same in every store around the world): Despite being of different shape the boxes have a lot in common: Their color, the texture, etc. So what you would do is put all those boxes into a single VAO/VBO and draw them all together using the same texture and shader through a single, or a handfull of `glDraw…` calls.

Comment: Ok so to sum up what you said a batch is defined by all the geometry (meshes) in the scene sharing same texture (materials), transformation and shading informations. So if my scene is composed of a house with a specific texture and one hundred of trees around it with another texture but with a different shading there will be 2 batches. Is it true ?

Comment: @user1364743: No a batch is not defined in that particular way. A batch is simply all the geometry drawn by a single call `glDraw…`. Don't overthink it. There's no geometrical or scene related definition to it. A batch is anything that goes into a set that gets processed by a particular call to `glDraw…` and that's it. What you aim for is collecting data into such batches in a way, that you minimize the number of `glDraw…` calls.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for all your responses.